# wrong value due to client side and server side integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a text area with id "text" and I am toggling the text area to appear on the screen with a click event on some div and I have 30 such divs. Initially , I'm assigning the textarea.value with result of ajax call to my fetch api which fetches the data from the mongo on the server side based on an unique id.

Sometimes , when I'm making the ajax call to my update api in my backend , the textarea.value I'm sending as data to this ajax call is not the same as the updated text of the text area.

```
//client side 
// called when any of the divs is clicked
$(".radius").on("click", function(event) {
//extracting the id from the class and using this id as the id of my data for my mongo
var st=event.target.classList[1].substring(0,7);
var num=parseInt(event.target.classList[1].substring(7));
var toadd="close-button"+num;
//console.log(num+"modal")
closeButton.classList.add(toadd);
$.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "/fetch",
        async: true,
        data:  JSON.stringify({
            id: num,
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success:function(result) {
          input.value=result.text;
        },
        error:function(result) {
           console.log("error")
        }
});
modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
});
// called when textarea is closed
function toggleModal1(event) {
    var s1=closeButton.classList[closeButton.classList.length-1];
    var st=s1.substring(12);
    closeButton.classList.remove(s1);
    var num=parseInt(st);
   // event.preventDefault();
   console.log(input.value)
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "/update",
        
        data:  JSON.stringify({
            id:num,
            text:input.value,
  //input is my textarea
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success:function(result) {
           
        },
        error:function(result) {
           console.log("error")
        }
    });
    modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}
```

```
//server side
app.post("/fetch",function(req,res)
{
      //console.log(req.body);
      // var id1=req.body.id;
      const findInDB= Fruit.findOne({id:req.body.id},function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
             res.send({text:docs.text});
       });  
       
});
app.post("/update",function(req,res)
{
  Fruit.updateOne({id:req.body.id}, 
    {text:req.body.text}, function (err, docs) {
    if (err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
       console.log("Updated Docs : ", docs);
    }
});
```

I tried debugging my code but couldn't reason out the contents of my console.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing `input` in your client side code, but I don't see it anywhere in the code. Can you check?

Update:

> the textarea.value I'm sending as data to this ajax call is not the
> same as the updated text of the text area.

I assume that you have an error in the code related to `input`. If you can add it to your answer, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I haven't put the whole code, only the necessary part.